# hazelcast SplitBrainHandler is not working in custom discovery strategy

Tags: hazelcast

System create hazelcast nodes dynamically, and register the node IP to a cache servce.

Custom discovery strategy code read IPs from the cache service.

```
<discovery-strategies>
    <discovery-strategy enabled="true"
        class="xx.xx.DiscoveryStrategy">
        <properties>
        <property name="ws_port">5701</property>
        </properties>
    </discovery-strategy>
</discovery-strategies>
```

When create some nodes at the same time, SplitBrainHandler not work.

System try to create some nodes. IP 10.68.170.221 and 10.68.170.203 is created a little faster, each one set self as master node.

After all nodes created, 10.68.170.203 can not merge to the 10.68.170.221 cluster:

```
2023-09-12 16:48:20.341 [hz.gifted_ptolemy.priority-generic-operation.thread-0] INFO - [10.68.179.203]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] We should merge to [10.68.170.221]:5701 because their data member count is bigger than ours [7 > 1]
2023-09-12 16:50:20.309 [hz.gifted_ptolemy.priority-generic-operation.thread-0] INFO - [10.68.179.203]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] We should merge to [10.68.170.221]:5701 because their data member count is bigger than ours [7 > 1]
```

I tried to debug 10.68.179.203 node, SplitBrainHandler shouldRunn() is not passed, which cause no SplitBainMessage sent:

[deug image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhvrH.png)

joinMembers is not empty, 10.68.170.216 in it. But 10.68.170.216 is connecting to 10.68.170.221 successfully.

The 10.68.170.216 node log:

```
2023-09-12 16:43:46.527 [vert.x-worker-thread-0] DEBUG - 2023-09-12 08:43:46[.527]|DEBUG|DFT_MSG_COMMON|class DiscoveryStrategy|null||| all Online Resource IpList is: [10.68.169.129, 10.68.170.176, 10.68.170.221, 10.68.179.203]
2023-09-12 16:43:46.612 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.IO.thread-in-2] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.67.131.216:32913 and /10.68.170.221:5701
2023-09-12 16:43:46.613 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.IO.thread-in-0] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.67.131.216:36729 and /10.68.179.203:5701
2023-09-12 16:43:46.615 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.IO.thread-in-1] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.67.131.216:45777 and /10.68.170.176:5701
2023-09-12 16:43:46.643 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.IO.thread-in-0] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.67.131.216:44733 and /10.68.169.129:5701
2023-09-12 16:43:46.677 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.generic-operation.thread-1] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] Ignoring master response [10.68.170.221]:5701 from [10.68.169.129]:5701 since this node has an active master [10.68.179.203]:5701
2023-09-12 16:43:46.678 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.generic-operation.thread-0] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] Ignoring master response [10.68.170.221]:5701 from [10.68.170.221]:5701 since this node has an active master [10.68.179.203]:5701
2023-09-12 16:43:46.681 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.priority-generic-operation.thread-0] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] Ignoring master response [10.68.170.221]:5701 from [10.68.170.176]:5701 since this node has an active master [10.68.179.203]:5701
2023-09-12 16:43:51.690 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.generic-operation.thread-1] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] Ignoring master response [10.68.179.203]:5701 from [10.68.179.203]:5701 since this node has an active master [10.68.170.221]:5701
2023-09-12 16:43:56.695 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.priority-generic-operation.thread-0] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] Ignoring master response [10.68.179.203]:5701 from [10.68.179.203]:5701 since this node has an active master [10.68.170.221]:5701
2023-09-12 16:43:56.725 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.generic-operation.thread-1] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] \n\nMembers {size:7, ver:7} [\n    Member [10.68.170.221]:5701 - 7e033290-0240-49aa-90d1-9d59c91cf6cf\n     Member [10.68.169.129]:5701 - 000570b6-ce54-4b38-a509-ccccb232094e\n    Member [10.68.170.176]:5701 - 96df61fd-0519-4396-a605-7b5c30934deb\n     Member [10.67.129.192]:5701 - 5c75e1e1-2b04-456f-813d-6aead629bcc0\n    Member [10.67.130.160]:5701 - 681f2e15-304a-496a-9866-64311e9d7436\n    Member [10.67.132.197]:5701 - cff314e4-25d5-4eb8-95ca-8d4f1e9d4b2a\n     Member [10.67.131.216]:5701 - a8f8ea30-41b4-495b-a4bf-3366d08ae284 this\n]\n
2023-09-12 16:43:56.738 [hz.awesome_ardinghelli.IO.thread-in-1] INFO - [10.67.131.216]:5701 [my-cluster] [5.3.1] Initialized new cluster connection between /10.67.131.216:5701 and /10.67.129.192:51829
```